# How to ignore a given console input

Tags: c, input, console, structure

My question (as the title suggests) is how to ignore the inputs in the console.

My program will take inputs representing first, middle and last name. For example, `stud.name.mdlename` should be empty if anyone does not have a middle name, it should be ignored so that it didn't take any input.

```
// write a program to read and display information of a 
// student using a structure within a structure.
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct studentName
{
    char frstnme[10];
    char mdlenme[10];
    char lstnme[10];
}Name;
typedef struct studentdob
{
    int dd;
    int mm;
    int yy;
}DOB;
typedef struct studentinfo
{
    int r_no;
    Name name;
    char course[10];
    DOB dob;
    float fees;
};
```

```
int main()
{
   struct studentinfo stud;
   printf("\nEnter registration number : ");
   scanf("%d",&stud.r_no);
   printf("Enter First name :\n");
   scanf("%s",stud.name.frstnme);
   printf("Enter Middle name :\n");
   scanf("%s",stud.name.mdlenme);
   printf("Enter Last name :\n");
   scanf("%s",stud.name.lstnme);
   printf("\n");
   printf("Enter DOB [dd.mm.yy]:");
   scanf("%d %d %d",&stud.dob.dd,&stud.dob.mm,&stud.dob.yy);
   printf("\nEnter the fees:");
   scanf("%f",&stud.fees);

   printf("\n ***Student's details***");
   printf("\nRegistration number : %d",stud.r_no);
   printf("\nName of student : %s %s %s",stud.name.frstnme,stud.name.mdlenme,stud.name.lstnme);
   printf("\nD.O.B- %d.%d.%d",stud.dob.dd,stud.dob.mm,stud.dob.yy);
   printf("\nTotal Fees :%f",stud.fees);
}
```

Comment: `scanf()` is for reading *formatted* data (hence the 'f'). If the data is not in the correct format (i.e., some args are missing), then try using `fgets()` and parsing the entire string for whatever present/missing parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should allow the user to skip the input, let's say, by pressing enter, leaving the buffer empty, I mean with `\0` only, you could use `fgets` for this, but a problem remains, if the input is larger than what the buffer can take, the remaing contents on `stdin` will be left there, compromising future readings.

I'd suggest using a more personalized method:

#### // Required headers:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
```

#### // Helper functions:

```
int clearbuffer() { // helper function to clear buffer
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){} 
    if (c == EOF) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int readline(char *buffer, size_t size) { // custom line reading function
    assert(size > 0 && size <= INT_MAX);  // validate size parameter
    size_t i = 0;
    int ch;
    // reads at most size of the buffer - 1, clearing the extra characters
    while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
        if(i < size - 1){
            buffer[i++] = ch;
        }
    }    
    buffer[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

#### // Main code:

```
int main(){
    struct studentinfo stud;
    size_t namesize = 0; //keep track of the student name length

    printf("\nEnter registration number : ");
    scanf("%d", &stud.r_no);

    printf("Enter First name(Enter to skip): ");
    if(clearbuffer() == EXIT_FAILURE){
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    namesize += readline(stud.name.frstnme, sizeof stud.name.frstnme);

    printf("Enter Middle name(Enter to skip): ");
    namesize += readline(stud.name.mdlenme, sizeof stud.name.mdlenme);

    printf("Enter Last name name(Enter to skip): ");
    namesize = readline(stud.name.lstnme, sizeof stud.name.lstnme);

    printf("Enter DOB [dd.mm.yy]: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &stud.dob.dd, &stud.dob.mm, &stud.dob.yy);

    printf("\nEnter the fees: ");
    scanf("%f", &stud.fees);

    printf("\n ***Student's details***");
    printf("\nRegistration number : %d", stud.r_no);
    if(namesize > 0) // if all three names are empty, no need to print this
        printf("\nName of student : %s %s %s", stud.name.frstnme, stud.name.mdlenme, stud.name.lstnme);
    printf("\nD.O.B- %d.%d.%d", stud.dob.dd, stud.dob.mm, stud.dob.yy);
    printf("\nTotal Fees :%f", stud.fees);
}
```

There are still some issues you could fix in your code to make it more robust, namely input values validation, which is hard to do with `scanf`, I'd suggest reading the input as text (with `fgets` or the custom line reader function provided above) and safely converting the values with [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) / [`strtod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof).

Alternatively you should document the behavior of the code in case of invalid inputs, be it values outside the range allowed or invalid inputs.

I'd also suggest the more precise `double` type, instead of `float`.

Minor issue, you are using `typedef` in your structure `struct studentinfo` with no effect, you forgot to give it a name.

Comment: Yes thanks!, for not only giving the answer and an explanation, As I am a beginner, I really get know much more things from this, and also able to understand the logic very well because of //your_comments.comments are very well defined.